# What ide is good for developing PyQt apps?

Tags: ide, pyqt, add-in

What ide is good for developing PyQt apps?

Comment: http://wingware.com/downloads/wing-pro  Yes, try out the Pro version.  It has all the debug tools you need.  Then throw down the small license fee when you're ready.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm using the pydev extension to Eclipse for Python development. Snappy, works in Windows and Linux, pretty nice debugger (comparable to the Eclipse Java IDE debugger). The code completion is able to tie into the PyQt modules as well.

If you're referring to writing .ui files, the Qt Designer that comes with PyQt is sufficient for layout of widgets, and pyuic4 will convert them to Python code for you (pyuic4 comes with PyQt).

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org)

[PyDev](http://pydev.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 9):

I've found [eric4](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/) extremly powerful. It loads qt programs to do the standard stuff (qt-designer, qt-linguist) and its editor and debugger skills are very very high.

Answer (score 8):

I've found [Wing IDE](http://www.wingware.com/doc/howtos/pyqt) to be pretty good.

Comment: sorry, misread the question. What is your platform? as far as windows goes there really aren't any decent free PyQT IDE's.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? There's no mention in the question the IDE has to be free. From the looks of it, Wing seems a fair choice, with a reasonably priced personal license.

Comment: Wingware is THE BEST python IDE you can get.  It's simple, fast, elegant, written in PyQt5.  Email support answered within the day or even the hour.

Answer (score 6):

I use PyCharm now for the most of my Python stuff (GUI, non-GUI, desktop, online, everything). The PyQt support isn't COMPLETELY ready (mostly is), but anything else runs without a glitch. PyDev was my previous IDE, it's a little complicated for me. Then there is Monkey Studio and Eric IDE, both done specially for PyQt, but both also pretty buggy.That's the main con for both of them.

Answer (score 5):

> I'm using the pydev extension to
>   Eclipse for Python development.
>   Snappy, works in Windows and Linux,
>   pretty nice debugger (comparable to
>   the Eclipse Java IDE debugger). The
>   code completion is able to tie into
>   the PyQt modules as well.

PyQT can be a hassle to setup in Eclipse but when it is set up it works pretty nicely! There is [a guide at popdevelop](http://popdevelop.com/2010/04/setting-up-ide-and-creating-a-cross-platform-qt-python-gui-application/) that shows you how to setup Eclipse in Windows to work with PyQT, with code completion and all.

Answer (score 3):

Why You don't use MonkeyStudio?

Answer (score 2):

[Eric Python IDE](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/) is the best I've found for PyQt.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using/working on an editor for the past 2-3 years called Ideas.

It's similar to eric4, its written in PyQt and uses the QScintilla editor for its syntax-highlighting, but I'm working on distribution bindings so you don't have to compile it.  Have it working for Windows, close to having it working for MacOS (works on all platforms though).

You can get it here: http://www.projexsoftware.com/products/ideas

The main features that I made it for are for wizarding (makes it very easy to generate new Qt widgets and code), portability (cross-platform and works inside 3d apps like Maya, Houdini, 3dsmax, etc.) and debugging - it has a full Python debugger.  Going to be adding pylint support soon.

I'll be adding more video tutorials for it soon, but there is a full user guide on the documentation site also.