# Python 3.x GUI Tutorials

Tags: python, user-interface

In the book that I am reading, it gives me a VERY short tutorial on how to use Tkinter and pyGTK, but nothing else. It just tells me how to make a helloworld application using them, which is obviously much more simple than the things I am aiming for. A google search rendered nothing much in the way of tutorials, and obviously the book is of no help. Is there a tutorial that any of you know of that helps you with those programs or maybe even a better option that those aforementioned two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used PyQt for Python 3. PyQt is already available for Python 3000.

http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download

There are lot of tutorials about PyQt:

http://diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Tutorials

I don't know aboyt PyGTK, but my experience is that it is quite arid. Anyway, you'll find more info, for example, here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993269/pygtk-vs-pyqt-vs-wxpython-vs-tkinter

And about tools:

[What ide is good for developing PyQt apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472021/what-ide-is-good-for-developing-pyqt-apps)

Answer (score 3):

Tkdocs.com has a nice tutorial on tkinter:

http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/index.html

And, of course, [the tkinter page on python.org](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/tkinter.html?highlight=tkinter#tkinter) has lots of information, including links to some tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

You could check these out, depending on the library you want to use :-

wxPython :-
http://zetcode.com/wxpython/

PyGtk :-
http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pygtktutorial/

The sites also have links to other tutorials for GUI programming