# Python GUI Tutorials

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, dynamic, graphics

I'm looking for good longform tutorials on creating GUIs with Python.  I've found one previous answers, but it's quite old (10 years) and closed.  What would you recommend? Any good example repos?

I want to have a dynamic user interface that allows the user to tab between different screens, enter data, and see output plots update (preferably live, but a button click to update would be acceptable as well).  Does this narrow my available options to a particular GUI tool?

Previous Question: [Python 3.x GUI Tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417840/python-3-x-gui-tutorials)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Edited to explain more about my intended use case.

Answer (score 0):

you have this tuturial in first link in English with PYQT and guizero in the second link(in portuguese)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MOItX2aKTGc

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCiTnSna5qYf9tC0mBScw2Rg

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).